# Simple pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in Haskell, and I tried entering the following in WinGHCi:

```
Prelude> factorial 0=1
Prelude> factorial n=n*factorial (n-1)
Prelude> factorial 5
```

But when I did this, WinGHCi got stuck and didn't do anything.  Why didn't it print out the factorial of 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write in GHCi

```
> let x = 4
> let x = 5
```

the second definition overrides the first one, removing it from the environment. This also holds for functions.

```
> let f 0 = 1
> let f n = 1 + f (n-1)
```

is equivalent to

```
> let f n = 1 + f (n-1)
```

which will recurse forever on any input.

In GHCi, you can have both using

```
> let f 0 = 1 ; f n = 1 + f (n-1)
```

but the best approach is to edit a `.hs` file, write your definitions there, and then load it in GHCi.